# What are the coins for?

Tags: mario-kart-7

I like collecting coins as much as the next person, but what can I use them for in Mario Kart 7?  Do I get a free life if I collect enough of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run over a coin, you get a short burst of extra speed.  Each coin that you get in a race, up to 10, will increase your Kart's maximum speed.

Your cumulative total of coins collected will unlock options for your Kart - including alternate Kart bodies, wheels, and gliders.

Coins will not grant a free life.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike in the first Mario Kart, where they acted as a buffer against other players crashing into you, coins appear to act as currency now for buying new kart components.

> Coins are to be found along a race track, and can be underwater, on the road, or in the air. Collecting coins on different tracks will allow the player to unlock vehicle parts used for customization.

Source: [Mario Wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_7)

Comment: In the first Mario Kart, their primary purpose was actually to increase your speed.